# How to create service in Android and consume it?

Tags: android

I am very new to the Android platform. Now in my app I want to create service and so please give me some info that how to create a service and consume it in my app. And how to start the service when the OS starts up?

Answer (score 0):

All the information that should be necessary, including examples on how to create and consume services, is available directly from the Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

It is doubtful that any answer could provide more insight into creating and consuming Services then that link.